# Can't open a HID USB device using HIDDevice class in windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, hid

The following code returns null in some Windows 10 systems

```
currentDevice = await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(devices.ElementAt(0).Id,
                               FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
```

I found out that this problem could be resolved by reinstalling Windows 10/ or using 'Fresh' option in Windows 10 which removes all the third-party applications. I can't guess which application may has a conflict with the HID device.

Just for your record, I can open a handle to this HID device using WPF Win32 application but in the Universal app I can't!

**New Update 7/11/2018**

After doing some debugging tasks using WinDbg, we realized that our UWP access is being failed because of some Upperfilters available on this branch: [Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class]. Some of these are made and controlled by Kaspersky anti-virus.

Looking for to see which/why kernel/user driver brings this limitation on getting access to the HID devices for just UWP Store applications?

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice.hiddevice) document:

> The first time this method is invoked by a store app, it should be called from a UI thread in order to display the consent prompt. After the user has granted consent, the method can be invoked from any application thread.

So, You could call this method in `Dispatcher.RunAsync` like the following:

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,()=> {
            currentDevice = await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(devices.ElementAt(0).Id,
                           FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        });
```

Comment: This is not helpful, please consider that this problem will be resolved completely when we make the windows afresh which removes all user-applications. When this happens, indeed there is no way to get access to the HID device using UWP with the mentioned code.

Comment: @Sansei Have you tried the [Custom HID device sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/CustomHidDeviceAccess) to see if it will work on your side?

Comment: No it doesn't work, but at the same time, I can open the device using a WPF application.

Comment: See the attachment where the WPF can open the device, but UWP can not. I tried many HID devices, from the many vendors but it doesn't work at all.